# Term limits for vice president already having served as president

Tags: united-states, president, vice-president, presidential-term

If a person becomes Vice President of the United States of America and the President dies after his 2nd year in office and the Vice President becomes President and serves for the remaining two years, can the Vice President become President for 2 more terms (according to term limits) after the end of the original 4 year term during which the earlier President had died? Would the 2 years served by him as President count in the term limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [22nd Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxxii), any person who fills an unexpired presidential term for longer than two years is only eligible to be elected to the presidency proper for one term. Otherwise, the two term limit still applies, for a maximum of 10 years as president.

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once.